# MongoDB GUI client (cross-platform or Linux)

Tags: linux, mongodb, user-interface, cross-platform

The [list of MongoDB GUI client apps on the official site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs) is outdated: some clients are not supported, some are heavily bound to .NET and not runnable on Linux. And all of them lack the ability to edit stored documents (i.e. provide read-only access).

I need a GUI client that:

1. Works on Linux (but not web);
2. Is free;
3. Supports documents editing.

Is there an app which satisfies these requirements?

Comment: I recommend and use [3T MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/download/platform/). It's available for Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: I just released a minimalist mongodb data viewer for nodejs [github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer](https://github.com/marcdelalonde/mongo-viewer)

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions.

Comment: mongo compass: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?filter=enterprise#compass

Comment: In 2019 (and beyond), there's now a modern Web GUI for MongoDB: https://github.com/huggingface/Mongoku

Answer (score 123, accepted):

[Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) - cross-platform MongoDB GUI client.

Update: Mac OS X and Linux(as Debian/Ubuntu, RHEL/CentOS packages) versions released.

Update: Robomongo officially changed it's name and released two different products Studio 3T and Robo 3T. Old robomongo is now called Robo 3T. Studio is for professionals.

Update: from October 2022 Robo 3T is named Studio 3T Free.

Comment: See item #1 in my question: i need a client that works on Linux.

Comment: See paragraph #1 on the site. My answer updated.

Comment: It looks interesting, hope they will do it for Linux. They use Qt, so it probably should not be a problem.

Comment: Mac OS X version released

Comment: Linux version released :)

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 7 as of today (build 0.8.5). First I thought it can't connect to local server. Then I googled and found I need to open Explorer. It's very non-pobvious @Artem. And now it shows I have no collections in db.

Comment: Does not support mongo 3.x with wired  tiger storage engine

Comment: Additionally: https://github.com/rsercano/mongoclient written in meteorJS, has most platforms distributions. Supports Mongodb 3.2 and older

Comment: It runs only on 64bit system. You can install it but can't run it. 32 bit systems become old now?

Comment: Enormous difficulty getting this to run if you don't have Qt5 installed :-(

Comment: Does this support raspian?

Answer (score 15):

try [umongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/), has releases for **Windows, Mac OS X and Linux**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this tool. This is very useful for me.

Answer (score 9):

Try MonjaDB
http://www.jumperz.net/index.php?i=2&a=0&b=9

I have developed this tool for myself. I use this tool on Linux ( Eclipse ).

Comment: You might want to try to add this tool to the [official list](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).

Answer (score 3):

try [Rock Mongo](http://rockmongo.com/), written in php.

Comment: which, by the way, is listed on the aforementioned page from MongoDB's website.

Comment: And is a "web" client, which the OP didn't want ...

Comment: and it's php.. which most of us doesn't want :D

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/greenmangoquery/
its light weight mongodb client using java . so its working all platform including linux and windows.