# MongoDB GUI Client for Mac in 2018

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, client

Stackoverflow's questions about recommended GUI clients are all closed and mostly 5 years or older.

What's your latest GUI client for MongoDB GUI?

Please note there are existing closed questions such as 
1. [MongoDB GUI client (cross-platform or Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227664/mongodb-gui-client-cross-platform-or-linux) (2011-2014)

But they seem quite out of date

Comment: This "self answer" does not belong here, as there is a reason why the previous topics are closed.

Comment: [Recommendations are off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), which is why previous questions are all closed. But thanks for the reminder at least to go an close all the other stragglers as duplicates to the existing closed answers. Those only stick around for the purpose of closing on any future posts like this.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried Studio 3T, Robo 3T and MongoDB Compass.

- [Robo 3T(renamed from Robomongo acquired by Studio 3T)](https://robomongo.org/) - previously voted as top option, only supports a limited feature of editing
- [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/), commercial counterparts of Robo 3T
- [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)

### Robo 3T and Studio 3T

[image]
[image]

### MongoDB Compass

I personally quite like MongoDB Compass as the UI looks much better, and feature-wise provides revert editing, geo query, visualizations etc.

[image: MongoDB Compass - Index Management]
[image: MongoDB Compass - Geo Query]
[image: MongoDB Compass - Schema Visualization]

Comment: All of the mentioned tools have serious downsides. I've tried about a dozen more, and to be honest there is not a single good tool out there for MongoDB management on the Mac as of today.

Comment: @AdamReis you are right.